# OpenCL kernel math outputs incorrect results

Tags: opencl

I am currently trying to implement an OpenCL kernel. The kernel is supposed to output a number of previously calculated elements divided by the total number of elements remapped to a value from 0 to 255.

The kernel runs in a single work group with 256 work items where LX is the local ID:

```
#define LX get_local_id(0)

kernel void reduceStatistic(global int *inout, int nr_workgroups, int nr_pixels)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (; i < nr_workgroups; i++)
    {
        inout[LX] += inout[LX + i * 256];
    }

    inout[LX] = (int)floor(((float)inout[LX] / (float)nr_pixels) * 256.0f);
}
```

The calculation before the remapping operation is for clean up after a previous calculation on the same buffer.

The first item of inout[LX] after the cleanup is 17176, the nr_pixels is 160000 so this should result in a value of 27 using the calculation above. The code, however, returns 6.

The relevant host-side code is as follows:

```
// nr_workgroups is of type int
cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(mgr->context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, nr_workgroups * 256 * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, NULL);

// another kernel writes into outputBuffer

// set kernel arguments
clSetKernelArg(mgr->reduceStatisticKernel, 0, sizeof(outputBuffer), &outputBuffer);
clSetKernelArg(mgr->reduceStatisticKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_int), &nr_workgroups);
clSetKernelArg(mgr->reduceStatisticKernel, 2, sizeof(cl_int), &imgSeqSize);

size_t global_work_size_statistics[1] = { 256 };
size_t local_work_size_statistics[1] = { 256 };

// run the kernel
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(mgr->commandQueue, mgr->reduceStatisticKernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size_statistics, local_work_size_statistics, 0, NULL, NULL);

// read result
cl_int *reducedResult = new cl_int[256];
clEnqueueReadBuffer(mgr->commandQueue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 256 * sizeof(cl_int), reducedResult, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Help much appreciated! (:

Comment: Are you sure you really mean `i <= nr_workgroups`, shouldn't that be `i < nr_workgroups`? And shouldn’t the stride in `inout[LX + i * 265];` be **256**, not 265?

Comment: the 265 there is wrong, the <= should be right. thanks! :D this does not change the issues with the result though, it outputs 0 now :/

Comment: Whether <= is right depends on how big inout is, which you haven't specified in the question. I assumed it might be nr_workgroups * 256 elements, in which case < would be correct.

Comment: Could you check if you didn't accidentally create an out of order queue? Just making sure that the kernel that fills the buffer actually completes first. Also, if you run 2WGs, you'll be over-writing memory. You may have meant to use get_global_id()

Comment: commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[deviceNo], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &status);

Answer (score 0):

We established in the comments that the global buffer index calculation is wrong:

```
    inout[LX] += inout[LX + i * 265];
                      ----------^^^
                      Should be 256
```

Going out of range on a buffer leads to undefined behaviour, so this is always one of the prime culprits to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue. I also commented out the whole upper block and the math was still wrong.

Comment: @vakyas If you still need help with this please edit the question to reflect the latest code (ideally with the definition of the LX macro as well), and please also provide the relevant host-side code (OpenCL API calls, data preparation/readout). The the current information is not enough for us to debug the problem.

Comment: @vakyas I currently can't see anything obviously wrong with the code as posted. A few things to check: **(1.)** Your command queue is in-order, right? If it was created with the `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` option, then your code is insufficiently synchronised. **(2.)** Verify that your input data really does match what you expect, by inserting an extra `clEnqueueReadBuffer` before the reduce kernel runs and dumping the data. (only for diagnostic purposes of course) **(3.)** I have a bad feeling about your accumulation code, as it mixes global reads & writes.

Comment: Expanding on item **(3.)** - none of the work items global memory accesses would appear to directly overlap, but awful memory access efficiency aside, I'd probably not mix global reads and writes like that. I can't find anywhere in the OpenCL spec after a very quick search that backs up my gut feeling, but I'd use a private variable `int sum = 0` and then write the loop as `for (int i = 0; i < nr_workgroups; i++) sum += inout[LX + i * 256];` Then, perform a global memory barrier, and only write to `inout[LX]` exactly once per work-item for the final result. As I mentioned, not sure about this.

Comment: The command queue is in-order. If I output the buffer right before running the kernel the result is exactly as it is supposed to be. For the sum, thanks for the suggestion! It indeed makes sense that this is not a very good style.